# Popup Error on blank EditText

Tags: java, android, android-intent

How do I require the user to input data into an `EditText` and not allow the application to proceed until the `EditText` is populated?

Right now, my application continues to progress even after the user acknowledges the error message stating the `EditText` is empty and is required.

```
         private final static int EMPTY_TEXT_ALERT = 0;

    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {

    switch(id) {

        case EMPTY_TEXT_ALERT: {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setMessage("oops!!")
                   .setPositiveButton("ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                       @Override
                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                           dialog.cancel();
                       }
             });

             return builder.create();
        }
    }

    return null;


}




        public void sends(View v) {   

            DatePicker datePicker = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.datePicker1);    

            int year = datePicker.getYear();
            int month = datePicker.getMonth();
            int day = datePicker.getDayOfMonth();
                 final EditText phone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2); 

            final EditText nameplate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);  

            final EditText issue = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);  



                     String ph = phone.getText().toString();
                     if(ph.trim().equals("")) {
                            // text is empty

                            showDialog(EMPTY_TEXT_ALERT);

                        }
                    String np = nameplate.getText().toString();
                    if(np.trim().equals("")) {
                        // text is empty

                        showDialog(EMPTY_TEXT_ALERT);
                    }
                     String i = issue.getText().toString(); 
                     if(i.trim().equals("")) {
                            // text is empty

                            showDialog(EMPTY_TEXT_ALERT);
                        }


                     else
                         {StringBuilder s= new StringBuilder(100);
            s.append(year);
            s.append(". ");
            s.append(month+1);// month starts from 0 in this
            s.append(". ");
            s.append(day);
            s.append(". ");
            s.append(". ");
            s.append(ph);
            s.append(". ");
            s.append(np);
            s.append(". ");
            s.append(i);

            String st=s.toString();


            Intent emailIntentt = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
            emailIntentt.setType("plain/text");


            String aEmailList[] = { "shreyas.t@gmail.com" };  


            emailIntentt.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, aEmailList);  

            emailIntentt.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Feedback");  


            emailIntentt.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, st);


            startActivity(emailIntentt); 
        } 

}}
```

Answer (score 1):

> *Shreyas Tallani*
>
> how to validate the phone number... enters more than 10 digits the
>   error message should be displayed

If you are just wanting to test the length of the `String`, just get the `String` and compare the length to the max length of 10.

In your `validate(...)` method do something similar to the following:

```
String ph = phone.getText().toString();
if(ph.trim().equals("")) {
    showDialog(EMPTY_TEXT_ALERT);
} else if (ph.length() > 10) {
    showDialog(TEXT_TOO_LONG_ALERT);
}
```

You could also make your `EditText` only allow numeric values. This would help you validate the numbers. You can do this in the xml file or in code.

**xml**

```
android:inputType="TYPE_NUMBER_VARIATION_NORMAL"
```

**code**

```
EditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_VARIATION_NORMAL);
```

---

First thing you can do, is add a `validate(...)` method. Inside `validate(...)`, you need to validate all the fields and if anything is left blank then show the error message and stop app progression.

If all the fields are fine, then call your send method. And `send(...)` should only be sending your data, not checking validation.

Comment: i need 1 more help... how to validate the phone number.. "ph" stands for the phone number... if the user enters more than 10 digits the error message should be displayed.:)

Comment: Added information regarding your question in your comment to my answer.

Comment: Let me know if what I posted helped you.

Answer (score 0):

You can add return statement after showing the dialog as shown below.

```
if(i.trim().equals("")) {
                            // text is empty

                            showDialog(EMPTY_TEXT_ALERT);
                            return;
                        }
```

It would be better to use Toast messages than showDialog though.

Comment: Toasts are sometimes a better option. But if you are wanting to force the user to notice the field is blank, you would need to use a `Dialog` and the user must press "ok" or something to close the `Dialog`. A toast does not require user input to progress and can sometimes be difficult to see.

Comment: @prolink007 : yeah dialog is better for my app...i wanna show the error to the user...

Comment: @prolink007 Absolutely true. May be highlighting the edittext and displaying an error message below edittext is also good option. It will be annoying to press ok if user makes a mistake.

Comment: i need 1 more help... how to validate the phone number.. "ph" stands for the phone number... if the user enters more than 10 digits the error message should be displayed. – Shreyas Tallani just now edit

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you are calling your sends() method, but after any empty error you can just add a return statement immediately after the showDialog().  It means that somehow the sends() method has to get re-invoked via the UI after the user has put in text.

If your sends() method is called from a button via onClick(), then it means the user will see dialog with error, input some text and then, hit the button to send again.

Comment: yeah that problem is solved :) i need 1 more help... how to validate the phone number.. "ph" stands for the phone number... if the user enters more than 10 digits the error message should be displayed.